# Expressing a function as sets operations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have the following problem, given the sets $A,B$ with $A \subset B$ I have to write an expression (using intersection, union, difference and complement) such that the result of evaluating the expression is $A$ if $A$ is not empty and $B$ otherwise.

I have been trying for quite some time by now but I haven't been able to reach any result.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you think it's possible? If we have an expression that evaluates to $B$, and then we add a new point to the universe and let $A$ be the set consisting only of that point, how can the expression suddenly leave out all the points of $B$?

Comment: mathSE reviewers are going to wait for you to edit your query with some of your failed attempts.  This will qualify as you **showing your work.**

Comment: @GregMartin would adding the condition $A \subset B$ solve that problem? That way the point would be present both in A and B and we could just intersect both sets. As you see, I am not very versed in set algebra.

Comment: $A \subset B$ is already one of the conditions.

Comment: I have to give up, I can't figure it out.  I think that the question in Greg Martin's first comment is a good one,  Is it possible that you have a typo in the problem?

Comment: Try thinking about it like this: you want to construct a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which evaluates $f(a) = \begin{cases} ab \text{ if } a \neq 0 \\ b \text{ if } a = 0\end{cases}$ using only addition, subtraction, and multiplication. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.  Indeed, note that if you had such an expression $F(A,B)$, then for each $x$, whether $x\in F(A,B)$ would depend only on the truth values of the statements $x\in A$ and $x\in B$, independent of what $A$ and $B$ are.  (That is, if $A,B,A',B',x,$ and $x'$ are such that $x\in A$ iff $x'\in A'$ and $x\in B$ iff $x'\in B'$, then $x\in F(A,B)$ iff $x'\in F(A',B')$.)  In particular, $F(A,B)$ either always contains $B\setminus A$ or is always disjoint from $B\setminus A$ (since $B\setminus A$ consists of those $x$ such that $x\in A$ is false and $x\in B$ is true).  But this is incompatible with your requirement: for instance, when $A=\emptyset$ and $B=\{0\}$, $F(A,B)$ needs to contain $B\setminus A$ but when $A=\{0\}$ and $B=\{0,1\}$, $F(A,B)$ needs to be disjoint from $B\setminus A$.